# How to remove unnecessary querystring parameters from url using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have following URL.

```
www.abc.com/xyz/?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=12&f=45
```

I want to redirect it to the following URL(through htaccess)

```
www.abc.com/xyz/?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4
```

How can I achieve above redirection?

**Note:-** Valid queryString parameters are  **`a, b, c & d`**, apart from this remove all these other parameters in new URL(redirect URL), and it is possible that these parameters can come in any order i.e. `a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4` or `d=4&b=2&c=3&a=1` is possible. And not necessary that these parameters come all the time, sometime some of them will be not in the URL(means its possible that only two valid parameters come in URL or three or one).

One way is

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (a=[\d]+)(b=[\d]+)(c=[\d]+)(d=[\d]+)
RewriteRule ^xyz        xyz/\?%1&%2&%3&%4   [R=301,NC,L]
```

problem with above approach is I have to write all possible combination like rules for when one of them is missing, rules for there all possible order.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to show forbidden access or something if not just don't append parameters you don't want to use in query string.

Comment: No I want it this type of url(contains extra params) to new url(which only contains neccessary params). Bassically remove extra params from QS